# Unable to save data in database through ajax in CakePhp after passing my own array variable in save function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

This is my view ctp page:

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php echo $this->form->create(null,array('url'=>array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'ajaxAdd'),'id'=>'saveForm'));
echo $this->form->input('ajaxtitle');
echo $this->form->input('ajaxbody',array('rows'=>'3'));
echo $this->form->end('Save Post');
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#saveForm").submit(function(){       
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:formUrl,
            data:formData,
            success: function(data,textStatus,xhr){
                alert(data);                                       
                }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my PostsController function

```
class PostsController extends AppController
{

        public $name = 'Posts';
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
        public $components  = array('RequestHandler');
public function ajaxAdd()
    {
        $this->autoRender=false;
          if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
             Configure::write('debug', 0);
          }
            if(!empty($this->data)){
                $inputData = array();
                $inputData['Post']['title'] = $this->data['Post']['ajaxtitle'];
                $inputData['Post']['body'] = $this->data['Post']['ajaxbody'];
                $data = $this->Post->findByTitle($inputData['Post']['title']);
                $this->Post->create();
               if(empty($data))
               {                   
                  if($this->Post->save($inputData))
                      return "success"; 
                }else
                {
                 return "error";
               }
            }
        }
}
```

With array as **$inputData** in save , whenever I click over the submit button nothing is being saved in the database.

But when I pass **$this->data** in save function, columns like id,created and modified are filled but the title and body column are left blank.

My **posts** database contains columns **id,title,body,created,modified**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code in javascript

```
$("#saveForm").submit(function(){       
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:formUrl,
        data:formData,
        success: function(data,textStatus,xhr){
            alert(data);                                       
            }

    });
```

You are not sending array in ajax request thats why you are not getting array in $this->data. but first run this code with `echo "<pre>";print_r($this->data);` in post controller to check whether you are getting data or not

Comment: I am getting data in `$this->data` in my Controller..i have checked it..\

Comment: can you paste that array here?

Comment: `Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [ajaxtitle] => Title 35
            [ajaxbody] => content
        )

)`

Comment: Can you try to change this line echo $this->form->create("Post",array('url'=>array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'ajaxAdd'),'id'=>'saveForm')); and then can you post your array

Comment: Why whats wrong in this?.. i need to use my `ajaxAdd` function in my `posts` controller.

Comment: Yes but you have not specified Post model when creating form so name of text box is data[ajaxtitle]. and at controller you have written $this->data["Post"]["ajaxtitle"]. so if you dont want to change in ctp file then change in cotroller replace this line $inputData['Post']['title'] = $this->data['ajaxtitle']; $inputData['Post']['body'] = $this->data['ajaxbody'];

Comment: Just try with replace null to Post in ctp file form creation and try to save your data. it might help.

Comment: The name of the text box is `name="data[Post][ajaxtitle]"` not `data[ajaxtitle]` . you can yourself try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 3.0 rather than an earlier version, you should be using $this->request->data() instead of $this->data.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data

If this is the case, the code should be as follows:

```
public function ajaxAdd()
{
    $this->autoRender=false;
      if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
         Configure::write('debug', 0);
      }
        if(!empty($this->request->data())){
            $inputData = array();
            $inputData['Post']['title'] = $this->request->data('Post.ajaxtitle');
            $inputData['Post']['body'] = $this->request->data('Post.ajaxbody');
            $data = $this->Post->findByTitle($inputData['Post']['title']);
            $this->Post->create();
           if(empty($data))
           {                   
              if($this->Post->save($inputData))
                  return "success"; 
            }else
            {
             return "error";
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: (Would have used a comment to check which CakePHP version was being used, but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to a post)

Comment: I am using CakePhp version 2.6.4